# Look for specific string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string that has the form http://www.abc.com/zyx/yxc/asd/?asd

I want to write a regular expression that reads only http://www.abc.com/  as the first 19 characters. If the search string is not in this location, it should not match.

I am able to search the string by using the regular expression `^[http://www.abc.com]$` but I want to specify the location also

Comment: Should it match the first 19 characters or the domain name. It seems confusing. If its just 19 characters, you will not need regex but simple comparison.

Comment: clearly no research effort into this question. To bad I can not set down-votes yet.

Comment: It should match both first 19 character and domain name.

Comment: You may be able to search your string with the regex you provide, but it will return always FALSE. Your regex is matching a string that is exactly one of those characters between the square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a plain [string comparison](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-index) if regexes sound complicated. Something like :-

```
str.index('http://www.abc.com/') == 0
```

If you want a [regex](http://rubular.com) it will be

```
/^http:\/\/www.abc.com\//
```

Comment: It will search the string in entire string, I want it to search only in 1 to 19th character, if only first 19 character are matching exactly the condition then it should return true. i am able to search the string by using this expression `^[http://www.abc.com]$` but i want to specify the location also..

Comment: @GauravSharma Does your language support the `substring` operator? `if(str.length >= 20 && str.substring(1, 19) == yourstring)` for example, with the appropriate string comparison function.

Comment: I want to do it in Ruby, and I don't think substring operator is there, there is a scan method to do the same.

Comment: Updated with the index ruby method and the regex tested at rubular

Comment: Also note that the ^ means match starting at the beginning of string, so this specifies the location as requested. If the regex does not solve your problem, perhaps you should give more explicit examples of passing and failing testcases.

Comment: `/^http:\/\/www.abc.com\//` is not correct. `.` characters in a regex are wildcards, which would let that pattern match `http://wwwzabczcom`. I'd use something like `%r"http://www\.abc\.com"` or pass the string into `Regexp.escape('http://www.abc.com')` which returns `http://www\.abc\.com`, then embed that into a pattern using `Regexp.new(Regexp.escape('http://www.abc.com'))` which looks like: `(?-mix:http:\/\/www\.abc\.com)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to check that string **starts** exactly with `'http://www.abc.com/'`, you can use [start_with?](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/start_with?) method as following:

```
str.start_with? 'http://www.abc.com/'  # => true
```

Note that if you anyway want to take a look at substring at **specific location**, you cat get it with [ ] operator by passing it a range instead of number:

```
str[0..18] # => 'http://www.abc.com/'
```

You can then apply any regex of your wish to the result of `str[0..18]`:

```
str[0..18] =~ /some [hard] regex/
```

BUT, if you want to check for exact match, the very first example with `start_with?` seems much more elegant as it doesn't contain any hard-coded digits and doesn't require a regex.

*P. s. **BONUS:** It was surprising for me, but [ ] operator (which is a synonym for `slice` method) not only can take numbers and ranges of numbers, but also string parts and regexes. So you can even do `str[0..18][/some [hard] regex/]` and it will return either matched part or `nil`*

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to work with URLs is to use a URL parser. Ruby's built-in [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) will do the job:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('http://www.abc.com/zyx/yxc/asd/?asd')

uri.scheme # => "http"
uri.host   # => "www.abc.com"
uri.path   # => "/zyx/yxc/asd/"
uri.query  # => "asd"
'%s://%s' % [uri.scheme, uri.host] # => "http://www.abc.com"
```

Note that the `path` contains the leading `/` so the proper host URL doesn't contain `/`. You can add that easily enough if you want.

Now, let's take a look at the regex pattern you're trying to use:

```
^[http://www.abc.com]$
```

This says:

1. The regex engine should find the start of the line: `^`
2. Find any single character in these characters: `"h", "t", "p", ":", "/", "w", ".", "a", "b", "c", "o", "m"`
3. The regex engine should find the end of the string: `$`

In other words, it's looking for a single character on the line.